# Reactjs: Disable button to avoid double submission, then enable button once request is complete (response received)

Tags: forms, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm creating a reactjs form that submits a form (with field data and a file).

When the Submit button is clicked, its triggers the `onClick` event that invokes some `handleFormSubmission` method.

This `handleFormSubmission` method first disables the button, then creates an `XMLHttpRequest` that sends the form data away. It might take some moment to the response to come back, and until then the button remains disable.

But once the response is theree, be it successful (code 200) or fail (code 500), I want the Submit button to be re-enabled so user can do another submission.

For the disabling, I simply set the state `isFormSubmitted` to `true`, and bind it to the button's `disabled` property. How could I then re-enable it?

```
handleFormSubmission() {
    this.setState({
      isFormSubmitted: true
    });

    // stuff...
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/some-uri, true);
    this.setOnLoad(xhr);
    xhr.send(formData);
}

setOnLoad(xhr) {
    xhr.onload = function(){
      if (xhr.status == 200){
         // request succeeded...            
      } else if (xhr.status == 500){
        // request failed          
      } else {
       // anything else..
      }        
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the state `isFormSubmitted` and disable the submit logic:

```
  handleFormSubmission() {
    if (this.state.isFormSubmitted) return;
    this.setState({
      isFormSubmitted: true
    });

    // stuff...
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/some-uri, true);
      this.setOnLoad(xhr); xhr.send(formData);
    }

    setOnLoad(xhr) {
      xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          // request succeeded...            
        } else if (xhr.status == 500) {
          // request failed          
        } else {
          // anything else..
        }
        this.setState({
          isFormSubmitted: false
        });
      };
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i tried this from beginning, but it didn't work: `Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload`